# How to do something when user scroll until a div?

Tags: jquery, events, html, scroll

I have a `div id="content"`.

Is it possible to do an action if a user see the `id="content"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered a similar questions at [horizontal scroll, detecting scroll position relative to anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244976/horizontal-scroll-detecting-scroll-position-relative-to-anchors)

### See working example http://jsfiddle.net/Vy33z/4/

You can also use a plugin if you are not too familiar with jQuery. The [Appear plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/) is great and easy to use. All you need to do is

```
$('#mydiv').appear(function() {
  alert('Your div is in view');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See, as inside the browser viewport? Have you looked at this [viewport selector](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) plugin?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't wanna use plugin

Comment: Why not use a plugin? That plugin is actually very small, you could just copy and paste its code into the page header. Or just look at it's source and take what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with this jQuery plugin:  [**jQuery Waypoints**](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) perhaps. Something like:

```
function scrolledTo(el, shownCallback, hiddenCallback) {
    var isVisible = false;
    var isScrolledTo = function(){
       var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(el).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(el).height();

        return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(isScrolledTo()){
            if(!isVisible){
                isVisible = true;
                if(shownCallback)(shownCallback());
            }
        } else {
            if(isVisible){
                isVisible = false;
                if(hiddenCallback)(hiddenCallback());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Contains code from [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling/488073#488073)

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/UFbw2/).

Comment: And How can do this with scrollTop ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check to see if the top of the div is within the window view.
This code would need enhanced in case you went below the div.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var divTop = $('#test5').get(0).offsetTop;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowBottom = (top+windowHeight);
        if(windowBottom > divTop){
            console.log('div in view');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="test1" style="display: block; height: 200px;">1</div>
<div id="test2" style="display: block; height: 200px;">2</div>
<div id="test3" style="display: block; height: 200px;">3</div>
<div id="test4" style="display: block; height: 200px;">4</div>
<div id="test5" style="display: block; height: 200px;">5</div>
```