# How can I achieve horizontal parallax scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'd like my website's background to feature a horizontal (rather than vertical) parallax effect when scrolling horizontally. The following jQuery code was used by me for making a vertically scrolled website; I've tried to make some changes to make it work horizontally, but unfortunately had no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $window = $(window);
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
        var $bgobj = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -( ($window.scrollTop() - $bgobj.offset().top) / $bgobj.data('speed'));
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where's your HTML? What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: @APAD1 Just want to point out that it's pretty clear what he wants to do

Comment: @Lochakocha Have you tried simply changing `yPos` to `xPos` and `scrollTop()` to `scrollLeft()` and `.top` to `.left`?

Comment: I want to make hroizontal parallax scrolling

Comment: @TylerH On the contrary, "I'd like to make my parallax scroll horizontally" is quite unclear.

Comment: @TylerH Yes I did that but didn't work for me

Comment: @APAD1 It is actually pretty clear. He wants a [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) effect when scrolling horizontally (that's left-to-right).

Comment: @APAD1 to be mor clear I want my website to scroll to right or left, no from the top to the bottom

Comment: @Locakocha that is still unclear. You can have a horizontally scrolling website without any parallax whatsoever. If you shared your HTML it might help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @APAD1 please, you are not helping. Do you know what the parallax effect is? No? Then read the link I posted. Yes? Then you know he wants a parallax effect in his background when he scrolls left to right. It's very simple to understand.

Comment: @TylerH, if it's so easy to understand, why are you arguing with me instead of answering their question? Oh that's right, because it's not clear what they're trying to do. There are many different implementations of parallax, you can have parallaxing backgrounds, parallaxing elements, etc. If their question is clear, then answer it and stop whining.

Comment: @APAD1 I haven't answered because I don't know jQuery. You are the one whining about not understanding what he means when it only requires the most basic ability to intuit meaning to understand the question. I have edited the question to be more clear just for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace the `yPos`, `scrollTop()` and `.top`with horizontal measurements of position instead. You can use [scrollLeft()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) instead for example.

[See this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244976/horizontal-scroll-detecting-scroll-position-relative-to-anchors)

To implement parallax, you need to scroll different "layers" of elements at different speeds. Foreground elements move faster (more pixels in the same amount of time), and background moves only a little.

You could achieve this several ways - with hard-coded pixel values by element type, multiplying by some speed factor, etc.

The code above only works with the "window" as a whole. You'll need to capture the elements you want to scroll separately & apply a horizontal scroll value to them separately as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this:

```
var parallaxDiv = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
  parallaxDiv = $('#parallaxDiv');
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var st = $(window).scrollTop();
  parallaxDiv.css({'background-position-x': 0 + (st*.57 )+"px"});
});
```

It depends on if you want the background position to change or the left/right position, but this should work.